# Using unnest_tokens() to split a column selectively (no split if comma inside a bracket)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidytext

I would be most grateful for advice. I would like to split my strings after a comma but need to preserve text within brackets containing a comma (i.e. not to split this). There are 4 possibilities in my data regarding whitespaces and commas.

1 no space after the comma within the parentheses (c,d)
2 a space after the comma in the parentheses (x, y)
3 a space after the comma outside the parentheses url.d, url.e
4 no space after the comma outside the parentheses url.d, url.e

In my example below url.b (c,d) needs to appear together as does url.h (x, y). In the code below, lines 8 and 9 need to appear together. Line 11 needs to be split.

```
my_df = data.frame(id=1:4, urls=c("url.a, url.b (c,d), url.c",
                                  "url.d, url.e, url.f",
                                  "url.g, url.h (x, y), url.i",
                                  "url.d,url.e, url.f"))


tidytext::unnest_tokens(my_df, out, urls, token = 'regex', pattern=",\\s+")

   id         out
1   1       url.a
2   1 url.b (c,d)
3   1       url.c
4   2       url.d
5   2       url.e
6   2       url.f
7   3       url.g
8   3    url.h (x
9   3          y)
10  3       url.i
11  4 url.d,url.e
12  4       url.f
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are commas in parentheses always without a trailing whitespace and commas outside always with a trailing whitespace? I.e. it always `(c,d)` and never `(c,[space]d)` ? And are those strings actually urls flowing a `https://...` pattern?

Comment: Thank you for replying. There is no space between commas within parentheses. I used the URL as a dummy example. I am working with other data that I didn't want to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(2nd attempt after test data update)

Here's one strategy to try out:

- use a placeholder character for commas in parentheses (let's pick `|`)
- use `",\\s*"` for splitting, it will match all commas with optional trailing whitespace
- restore commas

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidytext)

my_df = data.frame(id=1:4, urls=c("url.a, url.b (c,d), url.c",
                                  "url.d, url.e, url.f",
                                  "url.g, url.h (x, y), url.i",
                                  "url.d,url.e, url.f"))

# before applying unnest_tokens, replace commas in parenthesis 
# with a placeholder, `|`
my_df %>% 
  mutate(urls = str_replace_all(urls, 
                                "\\(([^)]*)\\)", 
                                \(match) str_replace_all(match, fixed(","), "|"))) %>% 
  unnest_tokens(out, urls, token = 'regex', pattern=",\\s*") %>% 
  # restore commas
  mutate(out = str_replace_all(out, fixed("|"), ","))
#>    id          out
#> 1   1        url.a
#> 2   1  url.b (c,d)
#> 3   1        url.c
#> 4   2        url.d
#> 5   2        url.e
#> 6   2        url.f
#> 7   3        url.g
#> 8   3 url.h (x, y)
#> 9   3        url.i
#> 10  4        url.d
#> 11  4        url.e
#> 12  4        url.f
```

---

A  closer look at `str_replace_all(..., \(x) do_something(x))` ,
`"\\(([^)]*)\\)"` is used to find substrings that are enclosed in parentheses:

```r
str_view("url.a, url.b (c,d, foo, bar), url.c", "\\(([^)]*)\\)")
#> [1] │ url.a, url.b <(c,d, foo, bar)>, url.c
```

But instead of a replacement string we'll use a replacement function that modifies our match and replaces `,` with a placeholder `|`
(assuming `|` is not used anywhere in `urls` column):

```r
# \(match) ... notation is a shorthand for anonymous / lambda function
anon_function <- \(match) str_replace_all(match, fixed(","), "|")
anon_function("c,d, foo")
#> [1] "c|d| foo"
```

Adding those 2 pieces together to eliminate all commas between ():

```r
str_replace_all(my_df$urls, "\\(([^)]*)\\)", \(match) str_replace_all(match, fixed(","), "|"))
#> [1] "url.a, url.b (c|d), url.c"  "url.d, url.e, url.f"       
#> [3] "url.g, url.h (x| y), url.i" "url.d,url.e, url.f"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I ran this code and have realised that there is a mix of parentheses with and without spaces between commas. So, this code worked for the ones without spaces. Is there a way of modifying it to include with spaces? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Please update your question and try to include those cases in your example data, same goes for strings outside of parentheses -- if there are cases with `url.d,url.e` (without a space after comma) that should be split,  include those as well. I'm afraid most of regex -related solutions you get from StackOverflow are only as good as the test data you can provide.

Comment: Updated with these possibilities.

Comment: @SK77 , you can check if this approach provides better results.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks you so much for your time and for the explanation. Much appreciated.